# Async wpf event with 'Task.Factory.StartNew' does not wait for await

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, async-await

The following `click button event` fills the `list` first with "B", then with "A".

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));

        list.Add("A");
    });

    list.Add("B");
}
```

**Q: How can I force the execution of .Add("A") happen before .Add("B") using the await async concept?**

**I tried:**

1. I tried replacing the `void` with `Task`, but the function could not be then assigned to the Click event.
2. I tried Task.Wait() function, but in little more complicated cases it results in a deadlock.

**Note:** This is a simplified example. I my real-world code I am calling a sequence of async methods, all are returning `Task` object and all are awaited, and still they do not run in order I would need. The function `Task.Factory.StartNew()` is used my real code in quite the same way.

Answer (score 4):

There are [a few reasons you shouldn't use `Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), but one of them is that there is no overload that accepts a `Func<Task>` or `Func<Task<T>>`.

As it doesn't 'understand' async delegates, it will return as soon as the initial synchronous part of the delegate completes - i.e. as soon as it hits the first `await`, in this case.

You should use `Task.Run` instead.